# Tkinter problem while using the text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, index-error, tkinter-text

I have this code to make each text "clickleable", from the Text() widget that has tkinter.
However, when I run the program and click over one text I get this error message witch each corresponding
text line:

`_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "This is the first string."`
`_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "This is the second string."`
`_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "This is the third string."`

If anyone may now a way to solve the issue, I be forever grateful. Here is the complete code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def text_click(event):
    index = text_widget.tag_names(tk.CURRENT)[0]
    clicked_text = text_widget.get(index)
    print(clicked_text)

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()

# Create a Text widget
text_widget = tk.Text(window, wrap="word")
text_widget.pack()

# List of strings
texto = ["This is the first string.", "This is the second string.", "This is the third string."]

# Insert each string from the list
for string in texto:
    text_widget.insert(tk.END, string + "\n")

    # Apply a tag to each inserted string
    tag_start = f"{text_widget.index(tk.END)}-{len(string) - 1}c"
    tag_end = f"{text_widget.index(tk.END)}-1c"
    text_widget.tag_add(string, tag_start, tag_end)

    # Bind the click event to the tag
    text_widget.tag_bind(string, "<Button-1>", text_click)

# Make the text widget read-only
text_widget.configure(state="disabled")

# Start the tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

I am expecting to print the text of each line when clicked over it.

Comment: You are using the inserted strings themselves as tag names - but they contain characters that have special meaning in an index expression, so they cannot be passed to `.get()`.  (The problematic characters appear to be space, period, `@`, `+`, and `-`.)  You will need to choose tag names in some other way - perhaps strip out everything but alphanumerics from the strings, perhaps just use an incrementing number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `text_click` function like this:

```
def text_click(event):
    index = text_widget.index(tk.CURRENT)
    clicked_text = text_widget.get(index + " linestart", index + " lineend")
    print(clicked_text)
```

This retrieves the index of the clicked text using `text_widget.index(tk.CURRENT)`, then it uses that index to retrieve the actual text by adding the appropriate `linestart` and `lineend` modifiers to the index.

Answer (score 2):

If you print out `index`, you'll see it's the string in the error: `"This is the first string."`. That is not a valid index. An index needs to be something like *line.character* or *@x,y*, and a few other special strings (eg: `"end"`, `"current"`, etc).

> I am expecting to print the text of each line when clicked over it.

You can use an index of the form *@x,y*, and you can use the `x` and `y` attributes of the `event` to create that index. Another alternative is to use the index `"current"` which represents the character closest to the mouse.

You can use `"linestart"` and `"lineend"` to translate that index to the start and end of the line.

Example:

```
def text_click(event):
    start_index = text_widget.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y} linestart")
    end_index = text_widget.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y} lineend")
    clicked_text = text_widget.get(start_index, end_index)
    print(clicked_text)
```

Comment: May I get information about `@{event.x}`? I couldn't find on website.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: the canonical definition of supported indexes is in the [tcl/tk manual pages](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm#M24). The curly braces are part of the syntax for [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) . You can get help on the attributes of the `event` object by printing out `help(tk.Event)` or `help(event)` on the object itself.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley for your solution approach. I will look for how to use the index in the form of @, x and y.